# Not getting unresolved conflict notification popup alert box in Subversive (SVN in eclipse)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, subversive

We are a team that just started working with Subversion using Subversive in Eclipse.
I have learned from [this guide](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~cytron/cse132/HelpDocs/Subversive/subversive.htm), (See Resolving Conflicts) that a notification popup alertbox is to be shown when two people make changes to the same file and then try to commit them, resulting in a conflict:
[image]

In our installation we are not getting this alertbox. I imagine that it may be a setting that we need to set.

Does anyone know how to get this alert box to be shown?

Answer (score 1):

I add to uninstall and re-install Subclipse. I had both Subclipse and Subversion plugins on Eclipse; I uninstalled both and reinstalled Subclipse and that fixed my problem